# JavaScript: put a space in jquery isn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tree

Hello I have build a dynamic tree view. I would like that the chield elements are among themselves. Because of this I have try to make spaces but it isn't work.

my js:

```
 else{
            childs+= `<li>${"&nbsp"+parentQuatatree[i].position} ${quotaTree[i].article} ${"("+getOrder(quotaTree[i].order)+")"} ${getOrders(quotaTree[i].article)}</li>`
        }
```

Comment: have you try the non break space: `&nbsp;`

Comment: @Frenchy yes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to inject non break space, you could use:  `\xa0`

Non-breakable space is char 0xa0 (160 dec)

```
$("#toto").text("\xa0\xa0" + t);
```

```js
var t = $.trim($("#toto").text());
$("#toto").text("\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0" + t);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<ul id="treeview">
    <li class="parent">North America
        <ul>
            <li id="toto">USA        
            </li>
            <li>Brazil</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">Asia
        <ul>
            <li>
                USA        
            </li>
            <li>Brazil</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not an adequate solution in HTML or in page structure in general.

You should create `div` for example on the left as a container, and give it a fixed `width`.

Then you should decide if you want to put that blue box or leave it empty.

```js
if (yourBlueButtonCondition) {
  childs += `<div style="width:50px;"><img scr='yourImageSourceHere.png'></img></div><li>${"........"+parentQuatatree[i].position} ${quotaTree[i].article} ${"("+getMaterialklasse(quotaTree[i].article)+")"} ${getMaterialbezeichnung(quotaTree[i].article)}</li>`
} else {
  childs += `<div style="width:50px;"></div><li>${parentQuatatree[i].position} ${quotaTree[i].article} ${"("+getMaterialklasse(quotaTree[i].article)+")"} ${getMaterialbezeichnung(quotaTree[i].article)}</li>`
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I can do that. Can you give me a Example code?

Comment: There, I updated the answer with a very simple example.

Comment: I have try it like you, but it also is not working